# Magento custom block takes long time to load with high number of SKU's

Tags: php, magento

I had a freelancer code a block which shows a slider of featured products, with tabs corresponding to the sub-categories within.

.phtml file is here: http://pastebin.com/6jEexZxu

Here's an example of the page loading with only 20 or so SKU's (it may be a little slow, this installation hasn't been optimized at all): http://crunchconcepts.com.au/test_store/magento/

The category structure is as follows:

> Slider (id=3)

-> PS3

-->Featured

-->Latest Added

-->On Sale

-> Xbox

-->Featured

-->Latest Added

-->On Sale

...and so on. This automatically loads a new slider for any sub-category of "Slider", and a new tab for every sub-sub-category.

This works great (although loading the products on demand when clicking to the next tab would be much better) when the store only had 100 or so SKU's, but when we imported 1000 test SKU's, the page loading hangs only when the homepage is accessed. The store runs fine on all other pages and functions, and only when the slider block is removed from the homepage, does it return to normal speeds.

It's running on a VPS at the moment, and the server load can spike up to 7-8 when trying to reteive the slider products.

Can anyone see why this is happening, and what I can do to fix this?

The freelancer has basically stopped responding to emails now that he has his money, so his advice is out of the equation!

***Update:***

Ok, so I'm trying to start from scratch, and I think I'm getting there... Or, at least, I'm learning a lot!

```
    <?php
$categoryId = 3; // a category id that you can get from admin
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);

$parentCat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
$childCategories = $parentCat->getChildren(); //Child category IDs separated by commas

$children1 = explode(',', $childCategories);

foreach ($children1 as $subCat1){
echo "<br/>";

$parentCat1 = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subCat1);
$childCategories1 = $parentCat1->getChildren(); //Child category IDs separated by commas
$mainCatName = $parentCat1->getName();
$children2 = explode(',', $childCategories1);
echo "<br/><br/>".$mainCatName;






foreach($children2 as $tabs){


$tab = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($tabs);
echo "<br/><br/>".$tab->getName()."<br/>";

$_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($tabs);
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
  ->addStoreFilter()
  ->addCategoryFilter($_category)
  ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name','url','small_image'));  


    if(!empty($_productCollection))

    {

            foreach ($_productCollection as $_product):

            echo $_product->getName();   //get product name  

        endforeach;

    }else{
    echo "nothing!";}


}


}


  ?>
```

I've got this, and it displays the category names and ids, but whenever I try to load products, it loads every product in the store! I tried a couple other ways, but it loads the wrong product from a random category. Help!

Comment: There is so much wrong with this code I don't know where to start. Do not hire this freelancer again ;) You can start by actually using collections instead of iterating through ID's and then loading a model for every product/category. This will be the main concern in regards to performance.

Comment: Yep. When you see `getConnection()` in a template, you can almost hear the money flushing down the toilet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its slow because you are running multiple queries with a massive result set, then repeatedly loading entire models.

Something like this would be *slightly* more appropriate.

```
$_catId = 999;
$_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_catId);
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
  ->addStoreFilter()
  ->addCategoryFilter($_category);
```

Then you can iterate through that product collection.

**BUT it should really be bundled into its own extension** and given a block and model for the specific job - where you could programatically pass variables to it, making the code modular and re-usable.

Then it means you only need 1 template file and could do something as simple as this wherever you need it

```
{{block type='mynamespace/mymodule' template='mymodule/slider_template.phtml' cat_id="5" limit="3"}}
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like I'll have to look into how to make extensions.

I've only just got my head around Magento's templates, so this will be  another nice learning curve! :)

Comment: I'm having trouble filtering the results to the current category. Could you possibly have a look at the new code above for me? :)

Answer (score 1):

The approach needs to be changed. Code like this should not be in a phtml template file. This needs to be rewritten as a proper Magento module with the Block class doing all the collection retrieval and filtering to get what you want. And the phtml only rendering your product slider display. Also, then proper block caching can be added so your pages load in finite time when cache is enabled.

There should almost never be a need to perform raw SQL on standard Magento entities such as products. Magento provides a good range of collection filters in the resource models that can be used to retrieve products and their information given a set of conditions. Also, special care needs to be taken to test this kind of code with both flat catalog categories and products enabled to make sure you can use this mode as it improves your Magento store performance for large numbers of SKUs.